# Csv to AzureAD Group

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a list of usernames that need to be added to a group. I've saved it as a csv file. I'm able to get their ObjectIDs, but I'm unsure of how to pass it to RefObjectId.

Thanks.

```
$users = Import-csv C:\Users\mine\Documents\M365_Roleout\Visio.csv 

$users | ForEach-Object { Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.name | Select-Object }
 Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId <groupidnumberhere> -RefObjectId <useridnumberhere>
```

Comment: `Add-AzureGroupADGroupMember -ObjectId $ID -RefObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.name).ObjectId`

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get "Get-AzureADUser: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null."

Comment: My command is intended to be run in that foreach scriptblock instead of your current Get- command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TheIncorrigible1 is correct, and I just want to formalize the answer so you can close the question.

```
$users = Import-csv "C:\Users\mine\Documents\M365_Roleout\Visio.csv" 

$users | ForEach-Object{
    Add-AzureGroupADGroupMember -ObjectId $ID -RefObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.name).ObjectId

    Write-Output "User Added to Azure AD"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement on the other answer for readability:

```
$userList = Import-Csv -Path "$HOME\Documents\M365_Roleout\Visio.csv"

foreach ($user in $userList) {
    $azureUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user.name
    Add-AzureGroupADGroupMember -ObjectId $ID -RefObjectId $azureUser.ObjectId

    "User '$($user.name)' added to $ID"
}
```